# Django fat model update field reference model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class Demand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="PREPARE")
    insert_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    insert_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def submitt(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk :
            demand_detail = DemandDetails.objects.filter(demand_id = self.pk).update(status='SUBMITTED')
            self.status = 'SUBMITTED'
            self.save()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Demand'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Demand'

class DemandDetails(models.Model):
    demand = models.ForeignKey(Demand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="PREPARE")
    insert_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    insert_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            try:
                super(DemandDetails, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError as e:
                obj = DemandDetails.objects.get(demand_id=self.demand_id, component_id=self.component_id)
                obj.quantity = obj.quantity + 1
                obj.save()
        else:
            super(DemandDetails, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.demand.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Demand Detail'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Demand Details'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['demand_id', 'component_id'], name='epm - DemandDetail (demand, component)' )
        ]
```

when I call the defined **submitt** method then I get this error:

> demand_detail = DemandDetails.objects.filter(demand_id =
> self.pk).update(status='SUBMITTED') NameError: name 'DemandDetail' is
> not defined

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error references a line

```
demand_detail = DemandDetails.objects.filter(demand_id=self.pk).update(
    status="SUBMITTED"
)
```

and the error message is for `DemandDetail` (not details):

```
NameError: name 'DemandDetail' is not defined
```

This could happen if you had that typo in there and haven't properly reloaded your (development) server since.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. 
Realy I correct model name without reload ( re import model )
After server restart everything is back to normal
Inexperience and beginner's mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing this easy step:

```
def submitt(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.demanddetails_set.all().update(status='SUBMITTED') # It will fetch all the demand details objects related with this demand object. You can filter by another field replacing all() to filter()
    self.status = 'SUBMITTED'
    self.save()
```

I think it will work. Let me know the result.

Comment: Your solution works as well as mine (it's ok after server restart). Now I have to consider which method to choose? The method explicitly specifying the model is readable, but Your method may follow more generally accepted conventions.

Thank you for the answer and your time